# keeping an array in order when props have been re-rendered

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm using react and getting an array through on props. 
it comes through like this:

`[ 1, 2, 3, 4]`

In my function component I rotate the props round and display the first index and display a list of the rest. Separating the first index into displayMeeting and the rest in to meeting list

```
const oldMeeting = this.state.displayMeeting
const displayMeeting = head(meetings.splice(0, 1)) || null
const newMeetingList = [...meetings, oldMeeting]
```

and set these to state. On an interval these change round.

```
[1] //display meetings
[2, 3, 4] //newMeetingList

//after 15 seconds they swap

[2] //display meetings
[3, 4, 1] //newMeetingList
```

They continuously go round. Some time these props change making the component update. How to I keep it that they stay in the order that they where last in before the props updated. They have Id's on them so I can use those, but I don't know how to bring the displayMeeting to the first index, whilst keeping the others in order.

Hope this made sense.

Answer (score 0):

Design your state differently: Keep an array of meetings, and an index of the current meeting to access. Then display the meeting at that index. To rotate, increase the index and reset to 0 if it goes over the array length. If the props change, re set meetings and make sure the index stays in the meetings index range.